# Android DJI-Mobile-SDK is hogging CPU

Tags: java, android, dji-sdk

I am using the DJI OSMO+ gimbal for developing an Android Camera application and I noticed that there is a huge difference in CPU usage when using the official DJI Go app (CPU Usage ~10% to 15%) from the Android PlayStore vs. DJI FPV Demo app (CPU Usage ~40% to 50%). Here are some details re my development environment:

Which DJI Product you are using?
- DJI OSMO+

Which DJI SDK you are using?
- DJI Android Mobile SDK V4.4.1

Which Android Device and Android System version you are using?
- Device: Pixel XL; Android System: 7.1.2 (Android N)

Which Android Studio version you are using?
- Android Studio: 3.0.1; JRE: 1.8

A short description of your problem includes debugging logs or screenshots.
- I noticed that there is a huge difference in CPU usage when using the official DJI Go app (CPU Usage ~10% to 15%) from the Android PlayStore vs. DJI FPV Demo app (CPU Usage ~40% to 50%). I used the "adb shell top" command to profile CPU usage.

```
DJI FPV Demo:
 6044 u0_a125  16  -4  51% S   151 1597524K 154936K  ta com.dji.FPVDemo
 6044 u0_a125  16  -4  40% S   154 1601524K 156208K  ta com.dji.FPVDemo
 6044 u0_a125  16  -4  43% S   157 1604996K 155932K  ta com.dji.FPVDemo
 6044 u0_a125  16  -4  43% S   159 1607068K 155640K  ta com.dji.FPVDemo
 6044 u0_a125  16  -4  49% R   163 1611676K 156136K  ta com.dji.FPVDemo
 6044 u0_a125  16  -4  44% S   166 1614516K 155000K  ta com.dji.FPVDemo
 6044 u0_a125  16  -4  43% S   167 1616440K 156840K  ta com.dji.FPVDemo
 6044 u0_a125  16  -4  40% S   170 1619948K 156568K  ta com.dji.FPVDemo
 6044 u0_a125  16  -4  43% S   173 1623292K 156680K  ta com.dji.FPVDemo

DJI Go:
 4009 u0_a158  16  -4  13% S   139 2261940K 223852K  ta dji.pilot
 4009 u0_a158  16  -4  13% S   136 2258952K 226304K  ta dji.pilot
 4009 u0_a158  16  -4  14% S   131 2253212K 227052K  ta dji.pilot
 4009 u0_a158  16  -4  14% S   130 2252356K 226992K  ta dji.pilot
 4009 u0_a158  16  -4  13% S   131 2253640K 223644K  ta dji.pilot
 4009 u0_a158  16  -4  14% S   128 2250664K 225868K  ta dji.pilot
 4009 u0_a158  16  -4  13% S   129 2251020K 226740K  ta dji.pilot
```

Note that CPU usage stays ~30% even on the ConnectionActivity (i.e. before even starting the video decoding in the MainActivity). Seems like a whole lot of junk on my device hogging the CPU for no reason...

Questions:
- Does anyone know what could be the reason behind this huge CPU usage difference?
- Please advice on how I can reduce the CPU usage when using the DJI FPV Demo app; kindly share code snippet or update Github with sample code.

Thanks!

Comment: For the record, this same performance is observed with the DJI iOS SDK. It's an enormous problem, and makes this SDK virtually unusable for practical applications that want to do any additional CPU work themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The code base that DJI uses for the official DJI app including DJI GO is different from the mobile sdk that is published for outside developers. As to more details as to why a custom app using the mobile sdk uses much more cpu - this would be up to DJI to provide a response.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK which is publicly available in the developer site is of Level 1. May be the Level 2 SDK which is issued only on specific condition has the solution

[Check this official video](https://youtu.be/sHF55hCI_ac)